# Use bazel library inside cmake project

Tags: cmake, compilation, linker, bazel

Is there a way that I can use a Bazel-based library like for example [lyra](https://github.com/google/lyra) inside a CMake-based project? Example: I have a simple hello world program, which is built using CMake - can I somehow use CMake to automatically build the Bazel library and link it somehow in my CMake project so that I can use the lyra library in the main file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, it turns out that this is kind of possible. I made an [easy to follow tutorial](https://github.com/GatCode/bazel2zephyr) on GitHub, which demonstrates the manual steps on how one can cross-compile a Bazel project and then link the result into a Zephyr project (CMake-based).

**Note:** depending on the complexity of the existing Bazel project itself and the limited capabilities of the toolchain you are using, you might not be able to integrate the Bazel project into Zephyr without serious code adaptation or refactoring on the Bazel project side!